# HttpModule with ASP.NET MVC not being called

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I am trying to implement a session-per-request pattern in an ASP.NET MVC 2 Preview 1 application, and I've implemented an IHttpModule to help me do this:

```
public class SessionModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.Response.Write("Init!");
        context.EndRequest += context_EndRequest;
    }
    // ... etc...
}
```

And I've put this into the web.config:

```
  <system.web>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="SessionModule" type="MyNamespace.SessionModule" />
    </httpModules>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="SessionModule" />
      <add name="SessionModule" type="MyNamespace.SessionModule" />
    </modules>
```

However, "Init!" never gets written to the page (I'm using the built-in VS web server, Cassini).  Additionally, I've tried putting breakpoints in the SessionModule but they never break.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Turns out there's a Web.config file in the Views folder, and one in the root.  Guess which one I registered the httpModules in?  Yep, the Views folder one.  I moved it to the root Web.config and now it works like a charm.

Comment: +1 because thats exactly what I'd done and this was what it took to prompt me to double check :/

Answer (score 1):

You might have to put the Response.Write in the method that subscribes to the EndRequest (or the BeginRequest) event. I'm guessing the Response object hasn't been fully initialized at the Init stage.

Comment: This didn't work -> var app = (HttpApplication) sender;         app.Context.Response.Write("EndRequest!");

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I had [HandleError] on the Controller Method, which was catching the error before my custom error handler had a chance to.