# ASP.NET MVC session per request pattern and IHttpModule

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, iis

I'm trying to make a solution like in *[HttpModule with ASP.NET MVC not being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391060/httpmodule-with-asp-net-mvc-not-being-called)*

How do I filter the request? I only want to open an ISession if the request is for an ASP.NET MVC action, not for *.gif, *.css, etc.

How should I handle this filtering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sessions are **very** cheap to create, I wouldn't bother with this filter.

Literally, opening a ISession is just a matter of a [`new SessionImpl(..)`](http://fisheye3.atlassian.com/browse/nhibernate/trunk/nhibernate/src/NHibernate/Impl/SessionFactoryImpl.cs?r=4912#l457). SessionImpl [constructor](http://fisheye3.atlassian.com/browse/nhibernate/trunk/nhibernate/src/NHibernate/Impl/SessionImpl.cs?r=4886#l195) and [dispose](http://fisheye3.atlassian.com/browse/nhibernate/trunk/nhibernate/src/NHibernate/Impl/SessionImpl.cs?r=4886#l1734) don't do much if nothing happened in the session.

Answer (score 1):

You could add the managedHandler precondition to your module. But I don't know how well it'll fit in with ASP.NET MVC because of static files passing though routing.

Anyway, you could try something like:

```
<add name="RequestTimer" type="MySite.HttpModule.RequestTimeModule, MySite" precondition="managedHandler" />
```

Have a look here for more information - [IIS7 Preconditions](http://blogs.iis.net/thomad/archive/2006/11/04/precondition-what.aspx)

HTHs,
Charles

Comment: Well Maybe I should just make an ActionFilter and add it to each controller. But I like the idea of an HttpModule

Comment: Did you try putting in the precondition? What exactly is it for? Could you go about tackling it another way?

Comment: No I didn't try the precondition. I will just make another solution. As Mauricio describes below ISession is cheap in creating, and if you don't hit the db no connection is made after all. Well I still dont't like to create objects I will not use. I will just make UnitOfWork in another way I guess, Might use some actionfilter

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
void IHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication context)
{
    context.PreRequestHandlerExecute += new System.EventHandler(context_PreRequestHandlerExecute);
}
```

And then you can check if it is the MVC handler (type `MvcHandler`) which will execute your request:

```
 void context_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
 {
     HttpContext context = ((HttpApplication)sender).Context;
     Type mvcht = typeof(System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler);
     if (context.Handler != null && context.Handler.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(mvcht))
     {
         ..... Code goes here.
     }
 }
```