# How to encrypt All URL in asp.net mvc 2.

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, encryption

Is there a way in asp.net MVC 2 to encrypt all my url in the project.

The project is done, but now the only thing I need is to encrypt all url.

How can I perform that without modify all my code.

Is there a way to do this in the Global.asax

Thanks a lot

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4464722/how-do-i-encrypt-urls-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Yeah, duplicate question, but not a proper answer.