# HttpModule Init method were not called

Tags: asp.net, httpmodule

Recently I was implementing a HttpMoudle. and stuck with the error which is said `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Here is my code .

```
public class MyHttpModuler : IHttpModule
    {
        private static IAuthProvider authProvider=null;
        #region IHttpModule members
        /// <summary>
        /// Disposes of the resources (other than memory) used by the module that implements <see cref="T:System.Web.IHttpModule"/>.
        /// </summary>
        public void Dispose()
        {
            authProvider.Dispose();
            authProvider = null;
        }

        public void Init(HttpApplication application)
        {
            authProvider = new BasicAuthProvider("achievo");
            application.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(Application_BeginRequest);

        }

        private void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)sender;
            HttpRequest request = app.Request;
            HttpResponse response = app.Response;
            TryAuthenticate(app);                    
        }
        #endregion


        #region private method
        /// <summary>
        /// Tries to authenticate the user
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context">The context.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private bool TryAuthenticate(HttpApplication context)
        {
            string authHeader = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(authHeader))
            {
                if (authHeader.StartsWith("basic ", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {

                    string userNameAndPassword = Encoding.Default.GetString(
                        Convert.FromBase64String(authHeader.Substring(6)));
                    string[] parts = userNameAndPassword.Split(':');
                     if (authProvider.IsValidUser(parts[0], parts[1]))
                    {
                        //the authProvider object sometimes is null .Why?                            
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        #endregion
    }

public class BasicAuthProvider : IAuthProvider
    {

        #region IAuthProvider Members

        public string DomainName { get; set; }

        public BasicAuthProvider(string sDmName)
        {
            DomainName = sDmName;
        }

        public bool IsValidUser(string userName, string password)
        {

            string sFullName = "LDAP://" + DomainName + ".com";
            bool bLogin = ADHelper.IsAuthenticated(sFullName, DomainName + @"\" + userName, password);
            return bLogin;
        }


        public bool IsRequestAllowed(HttpRequest request,string sName)
        {
            return sName == "joe.wang";
        }



        public void Dispose()
        {

        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Especially when multiple user get into the Website. the exception of NullReferenceException happened. and when I debug, I found sometimes `Init` method may not be called. Maybe that is the why the exception happened . Anybody could help me to check it ?Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is (as **Aristos** pointed out) that you have made the `authProvider` static.

That means that when several users are generating requests at the same time, there will be several instances of you `HttpModule` running simultaneously. But they will all share **one** `authProvider`.

So it's possible that **User A** starts a request, causing a new instance of you module to run it's `Init` method. Then the thread handling that request is put on hold and another request from **User B** starts, causing another a new intance of the module to run it's `Init` method. This will overwrite the instance in authProvider that was put there in **User A**'s request . Then *that* thread is put on hold and the previous thread from **User A** is resumed and finishes processing the request, thereby Disposing the `authProvider` (set by **User B**'s request) and setting it to null. After that the request from User B once again resumes and finds that `authProvider` is now null.

Based on the code you have provided, it seems like the simplest possible solution is to simply remove the `static` keyword from the line:

```
private static IAuthProvider authProvider=null;
```

Then each instance of the `HttpModule` will have it's own copy of the `authProvider` and one request will not affect the state of another.

Comment: Better to make the authProvider singleton?

Answer (score 2):

you have set as static your main object `authProvider`, so you need to make synchronize when you make it and delete it.

```
private static IAuthProvider authProvider=null;
```

So you need to write it as:

```
public class MyHttpModuler : IHttpModule
    {
        //can not be shared with others request.
        //private IAuthProvider authProvider = null;

        //We do not need it now.
        //private static readonly object _lockObj = new object();

        #region IHttpModule members
        /// <summary>
        /// Disposes of the resources (other than memory) used by the module that implements <see cref="T:System.Web.IHttpModule"/>.
        /// </summary>
        public void Dispose()
        {
            //authProvider.Dispose();
        //authProvider = null;
        }

        public void Init(HttpApplication application)
        { 

            application.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(Application_BeginRequest);       
        }

        private void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)sender;
            HttpRequest request = app.Request;
            HttpResponse response = app.Response;
            TryAuthenticate(app);                    
        }
        #endregion


        #region private method
        /// <summary>
        /// Tries to authenticate the user
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context">The context.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private bool TryAuthenticate(HttpApplication context)
        {
            IAuthProvider authProvider = new BasicAuthProvider("achievo");  
            string authHeader = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(authHeader))
            {
                if (authHeader.StartsWith("basic ", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {

                    string userNameAndPassword = Encoding.Default.GetString(
                        Convert.FromBase64String(authHeader.Substring(6)));
                    string[] parts = userNameAndPassword.Split(':');
                     if (authProvider.IsValidUser(parts[0], parts[1]))
                    {
                        //the authProvider object sometimes is null .Why?     
                        authProvider=null;                        
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            authProvider=null;  
            return false;
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

Comment: Hi, It seems your code still have some problem.please read user1429080's answer .One thread dispose httpmodule and set authProvider null .since it is static. at that moments another thread just found it is null . so your code still have flaw. see ?

Comment: @malai.kuangren Can you please correct the code when you made it work for sure ?

Comment: @malai.kuangren some else before me, is reject your edit, I am sorry for that and there is not way to get it back, so I do that manually from your edit.